# Syntax error on token "catch", Identifier expected

Tags: android, eclipse

Okay, so I was writing code and it was working just fine until I got to this problem:

Syntax error on token "catch", Identifier expected

Here is the code with the problem:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    EditText num=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String number = "tel:" +num.getText().toString().trim();
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number));
    startActivity(callIntent);

    TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)                      
    getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    listener = new ListenToPhoneState();
    tManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    //here's the problem 
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
        Log.e("telephony-example", "Call failed", activityException);
    }


    private class ListenToPhoneState extends PhoneStateListener {

        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            Log.i("telephony-example", "State changed: " + stateName(state));
        }

        String stateName(int state) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: return "Idle";
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: return "Off hook";
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: return "Ringing";
        }
        return Integer.toString(state);
    }
}
```

Comment: /me facepalms... okie... what have you '**try** `{` d' to do?

Answer (score 5):

Your error is because you have `catch` without `try`. I suggest you familiarize yourself with java syntax a little bit better before you attempt to tackle an Android project.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that I should give up on my app until I get to know java better? Cause that's not happening.

Comment: No, I am suggesting that you get a better grasp on java syntax before you attempt something so complex. I didn't say to give up on anything. Just do some brushing up...Its like learning to walk before you run. If you look around online for free java lessons you'll find some that won't take too much time, and you'll have a much better chance to successfully make whatever you are trying to make.

Comment: In general, is pretty hard to advance in Android, if you're not familiarized with Java. Believe, I'm a living proof of that :).

Answer (score 2):

Put a `try` block as shown below.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
    try
    {
         EditText num=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         String number = "tel:" +num.getText().toString().trim();
         Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number));
         startActivity(callIntent);

         TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)
         getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
         listener = new ListenToPhoneState();
         tManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    } 
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) 
    {
        Log.e("telephony-example", "Call failed", activityException);
    }
}
```